# How can I avoid Devise from requires authentication from within an engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, rails-engines, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm using Devise for athentication in my main application and
I have built an API (for a PABX) using "http_basic_authenticate_with" and it's working well when I add `before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:method_name]` to my controller. I'm doing that because `except: [:method_name]` will not require a logged user session on Devise and I just want to use basic authenticate for those API controllers.

`config/routes.rb` (main application)

```ruby
scope module: 'api' do
    scope module: 'pabx' do
        scope '/api/pabx' do
            get '/accounts/phone_number/:phone_number', to: 'accounts#phone_number'
        end
    end
end
```

`controllers/api/pabx/accounts_controller.rb` (main application)

```ruby
class Api::Pabx::AccountsController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: 'some_name', password: 'some_password'

  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:phone_number]
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  # POST api/pabx/accounts/phone_number.json
  def phone_number
    ...
  end   

end
```

The problem is happening when I want to do something similar to that API inside an Engine.
When I try to access the route, Devise seems to not allow to access it without an authentication, even when I'm using `before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:method_name]`.

`config/routes.rb` (Myengine)

```ruby
scope module: 'api' do
    scope '/api' do
        get '/accounts/phone_number/:phone_number', to: 'accounts#phone_number'
    end
end
```

`controllers/api/pabx/accounts_controller.rb` (Myengine)

```ruby
require_dependency "myengine/application_controller"

module Myengine
    class Api::AccountsController < ApplicationController

    http_basic_authenticate_with name: 'some_name', password: 'some_password'

    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:phone_number]
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

    # POST api/pabx/accounts/phone_number.json
    def phone_number
        ...
    end 
end
```

This is my the code in the main application

`controllers/application_controller.rb` (main application)

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base        # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    # Authentication using Devise (DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE)
    before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

`config/routes.rb` (main application)

```ruby
authenticate :user do
    mount Myengine::Engine, at: '/myengine'
end
```

When I try to access that method in my Engine, the terminal show me this:

```
Started POST "/myengine/api/accounts/phone_number.json" for ::1 at 2015-09-17 21:15:31 -0300


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2015-09-17 21:15:31 -0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
    Rendered users/shared/_links.html.erb (6.3ms)
    Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/authentication (29.3ms)
    Rendered layouts/elements/_flash_messages.html.erb (2.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 720ms (Views: 714.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

(If I'm doing something wrong or someone has a better idea, please share here.)
(I'm using Devise 3.5.2 with Rails 4.2.0)

Thank you very much for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, this was simple. Now I'm doing the authentication in my Engine Application Controller, not by routes on my Main Application Controller.

```
module Myengine
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
        before_action :authenticate_user!
    end
end
```

I also removed `authenticate :user` on my config/routes.rb (main application)

```
mount Myengine::Engine, at: '/myengine'
```

That way I'm able to use the following code in any controller

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:mypublic_method]
```