# How to apply for authentication of all routes from a Mountable Engine using Devise and make public only a few Engine routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise, routes

If I set the following code on my `mainapp/config/routes.rb`, all routes will require authentication and I will not be able to use `before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:mypublic_method]` in my controller.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

    authenticate :user do
        mount Myengine::Engine, at: '/myengine'
    end
end
```

Rails seems to need the mounted routes to be able to see the engine through URLs.

If I set the following code on my `mainapp/config/routes.rb`, all routes will be public, but I want to make pulbic only the methods that I wish.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

    mount Myengine::Engine, at: '/myengine' 
end
```

What can I do to make public/accessible `mypublic_method` (vendor/engines/myengine/app/controllers/myengine/mycontroller_controller.rb) using `authenticate :user`?

p.s. the same question in another way [How can I avoid Devise from requires authentication from within an engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642681/how-can-i-avoid-devise-from-requires-authentication-from-within-an-engine)

- ruby 2.2.3p173
- Rails 4.2.5
- Devise 3.5.3

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, this was simple. Now I'm doing the authentication in my Engine Application Controller, not by routes on my Main Application Controller.

```
module Myengine
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
        before_action :authenticate_user!
    end
end
```

I also removed `authenticate :user` on my config/routes.rb (main application)

```
mount Myengine::Engine, at: '/myengine'
```

That way I'm able to use the following code in any controller

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:mypublic_method]
```

Comment: How did you manage to test your engine inside your test/dummy application? Did you add devise as a dev dependency, so authenticate_user! doesn't error out?